# Jquery slideToggle can't work with $(this).find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select children '.comment' element slideToggle it every  time I click '.item' element.
html code:

```
<div class="row col-md-12 item">
  <div class="col-md-4">Name</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">degree of usage</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">price</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 comment">comment</div>
</div>
```

Js code

```
$('.item').on('click', (event) => {
  $('.item > .comment').slideUp(200);
  $(this).find('.comment').slideToggle(200);
});
```

It seems that slideUp effects can work normally, but $(this).find can't catch the '.comment' element inside it.

Comment: Arrow functions have no `this` of their own. `$('.item').on('click', function(event)` will work.

Comment: Just use: `$(event.currentTarget)` instead of `$(this)` if you wish to use an arrow function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is because you're using an arrow function, hence the context of `this` is in the outer scope still, not the `.item` element that raised the event. Use a traditional function instead if you want this behaviour:

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.item > .comment').slideUp(200);
  $(this).find('.comment').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the case. I didn't notice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put in a function into your js code. I also just commented out the slideUp as the slideToggle function will override it. See below:

```js
 $('#item').on('click', function(event) {
   //$('.item > .comment').slideUp(200);
   $(this).find('.comment').slideToggle(200);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-md-12 item" id="item">
      <div class="col-md-4">Name</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">degree of usage</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">price</div>
      <div class="col-md-12 comment">comment</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
$('.item > .comment').slideUp(200);
$('.item').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.comment').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Hope this Help

Comment: If you move the `slideUp()` outside the event handler they won't close when a new one is opened